# ReferenceInput and SelectInput first option

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a filter that has a SelectInput inside a ReferenceInput  and it has only one option.
I really need that first option to be selected.

```
<ReferenceInput  source="BranchID" reference="branches" allowEmpty alwaysOn  perPage={1000}>
    <SelectInput optionText={choice => `${choice.number  +" "+ choice.address}`} />
    </ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using default values on your form: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#default-values

Comment: Something like <ReferenceInput  source="BranchID" reference="branches" allowEmpty alwaysOn  perPage={1000}>
    <SelectInput optionText={choice => `${choice.number  +" "+ choice.address}`}  defaultValue={0} />
    </ReferenceInput>

Comment: Yes or directly in the form default values

Comment: Besides, I'm not sure about whether it should be on the ReferenceInput or the SelectInput. Probably the first

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: No it did work. I did not need it at this time, should I submit an issue in github?